# I can not understand clrstack result

Tags: c#, .net-core, coredump

Core dump test on Cent OS 7, using dotnet core 3.1.

This is the complete source code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test_NetCoreCrash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Test1()
        {
            throw new Exception( "Test" );
        }

        static void Test2()
        {
            Test1();
        }

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Test2();
        }
    }
}
```

Open core dump via dotnet-dump. This is the clrstack result.

```
$dotnet-dump analyze core.1800

...

> clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x708 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
00007FFFD14749B0 00007fa00291c387 [HelperMethodFrame: 00007fffd14749b0]
00007FFFD1474B30 00007F9F88AF0C32 /home/test/Test_Crash_Mine/Test_NetCoreCrash.dll!Unknown
00007FFFD1474B70 00007F9F88AF087F /home/test/Test_Crash_Mine/Test_NetCoreCrash.dll!Unknown
00007FFFD1474B80 00007F9F88AF0838 /home/test/Test_Crash_Mine/Test_NetCoreCrash.dll!Unknown
00007FFFD1474E98 00007fa001ef25ff [GCFrame: 00007fffd1474e98]
00007FFFD1475380 00007fa001ef25ff [GCFrame: 00007fffd1475380]
>
```

How can I get the correct call-site info?

Expected Result

```
$dotnet-dump analyze core.1800

...

> clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x708 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
00007FFFD14749B0 00007fa00291c387 [HelperMethodFrame: 00007fffd14749b0]
00007FFFD1474B30 00007F9F88AF0C32 Test_NetCoreCrash.Program.Test1() [E:\MySolution\MyMSSolution\Test_NetCoreCrash\Program.cs:line 18]
00007FFFD1474B70 00007F9F88AF087F Test_NetCoreCrash.Program.Test2() [E:\MySolution\MyMSSolution\Test_NetCoreCrash\Program.cs:line 23]
00007FFFD1474B80 00007F9F88AF0838 Test_NetCoreCrash.Program.Main(String[] args) [E:\MySolution\MyMSSolution\Test_NetCoreCrash\Program.cs:line 28]
00007FFFD1474E98 00007fa001ef25ff [GCFrame: 00007fffd1474e98]
00007FFFD1475380 00007fa001ef25ff [GCFrame: 00007fffd1475380]
>
```

(Sorry, I'm not native in English)

Comment: Hi @kkurrung. It is not clear what you you mean by "How can I get the correct call-site info". What do you want to get from the core dump?

Comment: You need to put the symbol file (pdb) of your application in the same directory as the dump file.